# Prove that a function is bounded

Tags: calculus

I want to show that $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 k -\log{n}$ is bounded..

Any hints on how to approach this?

Comment: You could show that it is monotonic, that would give you a good start.

Comment: $\int{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DanielFischer I get that $f(n+1)<f(n)$ since $1/(n+1)<\log{(n+1)/n}$. This implies that $f(n)<f(1)=1$. Is this correct?

Comment: If you mean $\log \frac{n+1}{n}$ and not $\frac{\log (n+1)}{n}$, then it's correct. Then show that $f(n) > 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $k\in \Bbb N^*$.
$$\dfrac{1}{k+1}\leq \int_k^{k+1}\dfrac{dx}{x}\leq \dfrac{1}{k}$$
Hence $\dfrac{1}{k+1}\leq \ln(k+1)-\ln k\leq \dfrac{1}{k}$.
Now use $\sum_{k=1}^n$ in the inequalities.

Comment: By using the sum I can get that $f(n+1)-1\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \log{(1+1/k)}-\log{n}\leq f(n)$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(1+\frac{1}{k})=\sum_{k=1}^n(\ln(k+1)-\ln k)=(\ln(n+1)-\ln n)+(\ln n-\ln(n-1))+\ldots+(\ln 2-\ln 1)= \ln(n+1)$. hence $\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(1+\frac{1}{k})-\ln n=\ln(1+1/n)$.

Comment: So $ln(1+1/n)\leq ln2$ and $ln(1+1/n)>ln1=0$ for $n\geq 1$ is all that is needed right?

Comment: yes,it's true, right.

Answer (score 1):

I bet this was already answered a dozen of times on MSE...

Anyway, [Abel's summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) proves more, i.e. that the limit (as $n\to +\infty$) exists.

We have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}=1+\int_{1}^{N}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x^2}\,dx=1+\log N-\int_{1}^{N}\frac{\{ x\}}{x^2}\,dx$$
and since $\{x\}\in[0,1)$ it follows that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}=\log N+\left(1-\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x^2}\,dx\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\tag{1}$$
where the constant middle term of the RHS equals:
$$1-\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot\psi'(x+1)\,dx =1 -\psi(2)\tag{2}=-\psi(1).$$
where $\psi=\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}$. The RHS of $(2)$ is also known as the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$.

Comment: The notation $\{x\}$ what does it mean?

Comment: Fractional part: $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor.$